# How to download entire netcdf-4 file?

Tags: python, download, dataset, netcdf, netcdf4

What I'm trying to do: **I've been trying to cache a .nc file from OPeNDAP (current and wind meteorological data)** http://thredds.met.no/thredds/dodsC/sea/nordic4km/zdepths1h/aggregate_be.html so that it gives me a file version that is the same as querying with the NETCDF4 library Dataset(http://thredds.met.no/thredds/dodsC/sea/nordic4km/zdepths1h/aggregate_be) using the [OpenDrift Library](https://github.com/opendrift/opendrift/wiki)

The original code from the OpenDrift Library in [their reader file](https://github.com/OpenDrift/opendrift/blob/f9f61047be2806f117c555e3d543b3aa2cb39747/opendrift/readers/reader_netCDF_CF_generic.py) looks like:

```
if ('*' in filestr) or ('?' in filestr) or ('[' in filestr):
                self.logger.info('Opening files with MFDataset')
                if has_xarray:
                    self.Dataset = xr.open_mfdataset(filename)
                else:
                    self.Dataset = MFDataset(filename)
            else:
                self.logger.info('Opening file with Dataset')
                if has_xarray:
                    self.Dataset = xr.open_dataset(filename)
                else:
                    self.Dataset = Dataset(filename, 'r')
```

with the filename being the url e.g. "http://thredds.met.no/thredds/dodsC/sea/nordic4km/zdepths1h/aggregate_be"

Methods tried so far:

**1. Filtering the data to download a subset of the dataset**
`nccopy http://thredds.met.no/thredds/dodsC/sea/norkyst800m/1h/aggregate_be?Cs_r[0:1:34],Cs_w[0:1:35],X[0:1:2601],Y[0:1:901],angle[0:1:0][0:1:0],depth[0:1:15],forecast_reference_time,h[0:1:0][0:1:0],hc,lat[0:1:0][0:1:0],lon[0:1:0][0:1:0],projection_stere,AKs[0:1:0][0:1:0][0:1:0][0:1:0],Uwind[0:1:0][0:1:0][0:1:0],Vwind[0:1:0][0:1:0][0:1:0],salinity[0:1:0][0:1:0][0:1:0][0:1:0],temperature[0:1:0][0:1:0][0:1:0][0:1:0],time[0:1:21690],tke[0:1:0][0:1:0][0:1:0][0:1:0],u[0:1:0][0:1:0][0:1:0][0:1:0],u_eastward[0:1:0][0:1:0][0:1:0][0:1:0],ubar[0:1:0][0:1:0][0:1:0],v[0:1:0][0:1:0][0:1:0][0:1:0],v_northward[0:1:0][0:1:0][0:1:0][0:1:0],vbar[0:1:0][0:1:0][0:1:0],w[0:1:0][0:1:0][0:1:0][0:1:0],zeta[0:1:0][0:1:0][0:1:0] norkyst.nc` which gives me a small file that is missing a lot of data (Can be read as reader but using ncdump shows that ubar etc data is missing)

**2. Try to download the entire dataset** 
`nccopy -4 http://thredds.met.no/thredds/dodsC/sea/norkyst800m/1h/aggregate_be norkystFull.nc` which leads to 33GB file that quits downloading at that point. (Gives the HDF Error)

Comment: Do you need entire dataset? Perhaps you can also download it step-by-step i.e. every time-step separately and when you have all timesteps, then you can manipulate with the dataset as you see fit. HDF error in my experience indicates some network problems (not problems with netCDF file itself). Most likely after downloading 33GB (whatever that is in time), the network connection is killed and you see that HDF error message.

Answer (score 0):

There is a maximum amount of data that OPeNDAP in THREDDS will let you download in a single access, which may prevent you downloading the whole aggregation with one command.  You could get around this by downloading subsets and then cocatenating them locally.  For example, if you have [NCO utilities](http://nco.sourceforge.net/) installed, you can download the subsets to local netCDF files by using `ncks` with a time-domain subsetting option, and then do the concatenation using `ncrcat`.

For example, the following will download a subset with time dimension indices ranging from 2 to 3 (inclusive) to the local file `subset.nc`.  Also on the fly it will make the time dimension into an unlimited dimension in the output netCDF file; this will make it easier to use `ncrcat` afterwards, as that requires an unlimited dimension.

```
url=https://thredds.met.no/thredds/dodsC/sea/nordic4km/zdepths1h/aggregate_be

ncks -d time,2,3 --mk_rec_dmn time $url subset.nc
```

You can then do the concatenation using something like:

```
ncrcat subset1.nc [subset2.nc ...] whole_series.nc
```

If not all the variables are of interest, you can use e.g. `-v temperature,salinity` on the `ncks` command to download just the specified variables together with associated coordinate variables.